# Verify with Gauss theorem $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Verify with Gauss theorem $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$ when the region is $0 \le z \le 1 - x^2 - y^2$

Following the formula of the theorem, I get using the partial derivates $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = 3$

Plugging this in $$\int_{0 \le z \le1-x^2-y^2} 3 \cdot dV$$

I've attempted the region though I'm finding it difficult given that I haven't faced an inequality like this before.

At first thought, I thought I could do this $0\le z \le 1-r^2$ and represent it in cylindrical coordinates in some way. I would appreciate some guidance on how to proceed!

Something like $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-r^2}$

Comment: Isn't $0\le z \le 1-r^2$ already in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: So, when is $1-x^2-y^2 = 0$, so that the upper and lower bounds on $z$ match?  This should tell you the range of possible $x$s and the range of possible $y$s (and the boundary of the region of feasible $(x,y)$ pairs).

Comment: The bounds you give for the triple integral look correct to me. (assuming the order $dz dr d\theta$ - also don't forget the extra $r$ for the Jacobian)

Comment: If you're asked to verify Gauss's divergence theorem you need to show that this triple integral (whose bounds you identified correctly) equals the sum of two appropriate flux integrals. One of the flux integrals has domain of integration $$S_1=\{(x,y,z): z=0,x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$$ while the other flux integral has domain $$S_2=\{(x,y,z):z=1-x^2-y^2,z\geq 0\}$$